# Check whether an object with its unique together fields exist to create or delete before saving

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Please consider this Ticket model, where its two fields (`show` and `seat`) should be unique together. Also it has a boolean field (`paid`) to indicate whether the ticket is paid or not.

model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('show', 'seat')
```

This is an example of the client side data

```
[
    {u'seat': 6, u'user': 3, u'show': 2}, 
    {u'seat': 7, u'user': 3, u'show': 2}
]
```

And the views:

```
def buy_ticket(request):
    serialized = TicketSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        serialized.save()
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I would like to do is check whether there is any Ticket with the provided data (`seat` and `show`). If there is no such Ticket then create a new one. Or else, if there is a Ticket, then check if that ticket has been paid. If its not paid then delete that ticket and create a new one with the new data, or else raise an error.

I tried doing this way in the serializer, but I am still getting a uniqueness error:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            ticket = Ticket.objects.get(seat=data['seat'], show=data['show'])
            if not ticket.paid:
                ticket.delete()
                return data
        except Ticket.DoesNotExist:
            return data
```

Comment: May not be the source of your uniqueness error, but I think you have a race condition in there. You'll want to make sure this is wrapped in a transaction or implement some kind of locking that persists between your delete() and create() calls.

Comment: @whp I am sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please explain a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: Don't do this in the serializer. This is a task of the model manager or a view. Serializer should turn model into json and not do anything else.

Comment: @Melvyn Ok. Got it! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Aamu - Sure, you're modifying a ticket object in a series of steps that are non idempotent. Presumably, this is going to run on a web server that might be processing multiple requests about the same `Ticket` at about the same time, so you might still get occasional errors if separate processes interleave their queries to the DB. Put the transaction around the parts of your code that execute queries.

Comment: @whp Thank you for your advice! I will surely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_or_create`:

```
ticket, created = Ticket.objects.get_or_create(seat=data['seat'], show=data['show'], user=data['user'])
if not created and not ticket.paid:
    ticket.delete()
return data
```

You need `user` as it is a required field.

Answer (score 0):

From the suggestion of [whp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7770091/whp), and modifying the answer of [The_Cthulhu_Kid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091551/the-cthulhu-kid), try this

```
from django.db import transaction

class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):

        with transaction.atomic():
            ticket, created = Ticket.objects.get_or_create(seat=data['seat'], show=data['show'], user=data['user'])
            if not created and not ticket.paid:
                ticket.delete()
            else:
                raise ValidationError("Your error here")
        return data
```

Comment: Inyour form validation, I suppose. In your `validate()` method. Should I edit my answer to include the rest.